# css, disable display: none;

Tags: css

I have this situation in my code:

```
<!-- This is the global CSS file -->
<style type="text/css">
#show_div{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<!-- This is the local CSS file (only in this page)-->
<style type="text/css">
#show_div{
    /* However to disable display: none;*/  
}
</style>
<body>
<div id = "show_div">
    Text text
</div>
```

I usually need to hide this element, but on one page, I need to show it. In global css file I have:

```
#show_div{
    display: none;
}
```

How can I disable `display: none;`?
I can not use jQuery, `$('#show_div').show();` (or JavaScript).

Thanks

If you do not understand my problem, then I apologize. I can try to explain again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the body class or id of the page you want it to be visible on

```
<style>
#show_table #show_div{
display:block!important;
}
</style>


<body id='show_table'>
<div id='show_div'>
text text 
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this not work if the element is a flex though? How do you undo a `display: none` that was applied  to any other generic types of display?

Answer (score 6):

Use `display: block` to get the default `display` for a `<div>` element, like tis:

```
#show_div { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set it to a [different value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop), but it sounds like you'd be better off just including the content in the page you want it to appear in instead of putting it everywhere and hiding it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `!important` in front of your style on the single page to override previous style definitions.

```
#show_div {
display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make it without `!important` ?

Comment: Yes, you may not need it because it depends on where the CSS rule is placed, the order it appears, etc. There are a few articles describing this in detail. Check the top response for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css