# How to remove <td> border in bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help, my css override for my table-bordered table seems not working. I'm trying to create a table something like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Collection 1</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Collection 2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="no-line">-----------</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total </td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the css, I tried all possible combinations just to check which will work but still it does not remove the border.

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td.no-line {
border:none !important;
border-right: none !important;
border-left: none !important;
border-top: none !important;
border-right-style: none !important;
border-left-style: none !important;
}
```

Please help, Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: its simple just add class table-bordered{border:0px;} or table-bordered{border:none;} any of them you can use.

Answer (score 8):

Its actually removing the border. The border that you still see is the table border. [Check this fiddle with your original code](https://jsfiddle.net/4yczcfg5/1/)

Once you remove the table border

```
.table-bordered{
  border:none;
}
```

The borders will be gone. [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yczcfg5/2/)

Comment: Wow! this worked. I've figured that it was the table's border but I was hesitant to add border:none to .table-bordered because I taught it will affect the whole table. I'm still a newbie and I learned something new today. Thank you very much!

Comment: Technically, it does remove the whole table border, but it doesn't matter since the row borders are still there, hence you'll never notice if table border exists unless they are different in color and size.

Comment: Btw, what is the appropriate property for bootstrap to remove borders? Is it border:none or border-top: none ?

Comment: `border:none` works. Also, Its just regular css, there nothing different here. All that matters is [css order of precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for sharing and taking time to help.

Answer (score 4):

For a specific  remove border

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >Collection 1</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="noborder">Collection 2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="no-line">-----------</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total </td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<style>

.noborder{
      border: none!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi dkc007, thanks for the reply. Will this work for a specific <td> element only? I don't want the whole table to have no borders.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bootstrap, no need to create custom css or modify the exists css use CDN

```html
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Collection 1</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Collection 2</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="no-line">-----------</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total </td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

see this

```css
.table-bordered, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td {
border:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Collection 1</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Collection 2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="no-line">-----------</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total </td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```