# can't change the font-size of anchor tag after link visit

Tags: html, css

I am not able to change the `font-size` of the anchor tag after the link is visited

**Here is my code:**

```css
         a:visited{
            font-size: 40px;
            }
```

```html
  <html>
        <head>
            <title>CSS</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            </head>
        <body>
            
            <a href="https://youtube.com">Youtube</a>
        </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: The css link (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`) should be **inside** the `<head>` tag!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change font size in css visited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375826/how-to-change-font-size-in-css-visited)

Comment: Here is a full list of allowed styles on `a:visited`

 - color, background-color, border-color (and border-color for separate
   sides), outline color, column-rule-color, the color parts of fill and
   stroke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are strict limits on what changes can be made inside a `:visited` psuedo-class, and `font-size` changes are forbidden there.

This is because it would change the size of the element, which would move things on the page around, which could be measured using JS, which would allow a website to determine which URLs a person had visited. (A security and privacy issue).

[MDN has a detailed list of the restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).