# How to prevent bootstrap to make changes in included files?

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-4

I have included bootstrap css in my page demo.php using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and js file:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have used this to include a progress bar plugin. Also I included a file (filename1.php). But when I use bootstrap it affects my included files (filename1.php) style, that I don't want to happen. Can somebody help me to find a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the bootstrap styles before your styles and then yours (may) take precedence.  But you also need to consider specificity.  See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/2181514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Comment: @freedomn-m I have put the bootstrap file before my style in demo.php ,so it not affecting my custom styles.  But I dont know how to avoid it affecting the included file ('filename1.php').

Comment: Can't you put it before the included file?   Is in the included file before the `<head>` of your output?  You might be misunderstanding what an 'included file' is - it's not a separate, isolated piece of functionality, it's just a way to organise the content - the *final* html is still a single serial html file (with your page inserted at the appropriate location).