# CSS new class does not override specific element style?

Tags: javascript, css

In the following code, the div "main" switches from class "main1" to "main2".
Testing demonstrates that the new class **is** applied (size changes from 100x200 to 200x100),
however the new class does **not** override the background-color assigned previsouly to the div.
Is this the normal behavior?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .main1 {width:100px; height:200px; background-color:yellow;}
      .main2 {width:200px; height:100px; background-color:orange;}
    </style>
    <script>
      function start() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("main").className = "main2";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="start();">
    <div id="main" class="main1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, Because div CSS will be loaded first.

Comment: css specificity rules state that inline styles have higher specificity than any stylesheet styles `document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundColor = "green";` rules the roost

Answer (score 2):

**Inline** style (`green`) have more precedence over **class** styles.(`yellow` and `orange`. So inline styles will be applied in this case unless you have a more precedented selector say something using `!important`

check this answer:
[What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Comment: to be clear ... `!important` is the **only** way to override inline style attribute

Answer (score 0):

Because Inline CSS loaded first, If any how you wants to apply **background-color:orange**; then add **!important** like **background-color:orange !important;**