# setting properties of a class with multiple names

Tags: html, css

This is basic, might be wrong .

Some classes have multiple names inside, for instance in `Bootstrap` :

```
 <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg sticky-top'>
```

I am trying to understand this subject :

1. Using a name for a class let you set properties in `CSS` with this name, if so, why some classes gets multiple names- like this one above ?
2. If a class has multiple names, how do you set its `CSS` properties, by which name ?
3. If you have a class, and another inside, and you first set properties to the top(which affect the inner) and then you drill in and set different properties to the inner, will it override the outer ?

For example:

```
<div class="=collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
               <li class="nav-item">
```

How would I edit the `nav-item` class text color? how do you drill into it in `CSS`?

So this will not work :

```
 .nav-item{
    text-align: right;
     color: aqua

}
```

It looks like a mess with all those names, unlike coding in `C++` or other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically different classes handle different styles for the tag they are defined on.

1. The reason can be implied from my first sentences. They are used to specify different stylings on the object they are applied to and they are used to separate styles for reuse on different manifestations of the object
2. This depends on what you want to achieve and what you want to modify. Take a look in the developer tools of your browser. There you can inspect what each class does and what stylings they apply on the current tag. If you want to modify something you have to find out which class does what. In you case we are talking about [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) and you find on their homepage what the different classes do and are used for.
3. If you have multiple classes and one does override the other class there are specific rules for that. This doesn't depend on the class order within the `class=` attribute but rather is controlled by the order of the selectors in your CSS stylings e.g.

```
    .navbar-default{ color: white; }
    .navbar{ color: red; }
```

The CSS above does style the `color` of the text red and not white even if the `navbar` class is in the HTML markup listed first. The latest / last defined CSS is important. There are more rules which define the priority of the stylings based on CSS selectors. I would suggest that you put some time in reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) because you need to build up some basic knowledge on how CSS works.

Comment: @Curnelious You are welcome, I hope this helps you, I tried to keep it generic and more focused on the concept rather than actually focusing on Bootstrap.

Comment: So if I take a big block of classes and put them all inside a container, can I simply ask the container to set the fonts and colors to all of its childs ? I am not getting this yet.

Comment: @Curnelious Yes you can do this however if there are stylings set on children, they might override your stylings set on the parent container. If they are more specific they override the more general stylings (from the parent container). Also not all stylings are inherited by child containers from their parents. But font and color are inherited IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Using a name for a class let you set properties in CSS with this name, if so, why some classes gets multiple names- like this one above ?

This is by design by the bootstrap team. You may want the css properties of `navbar` but not want your navbar to expand at the large media breakpoint (`navbar-expand-lg`). You instead may want your navbar to expand at the medium breakpoint, so you could do `class="navbar navbar-expand-md"`. These multiple classes allow the develop to apply different classes (and in turn different css properties) based on their needs.

2. > If a class has multiple names, how do you set its CSS properties, by which name ?

You can apply your custom styles to any class name. (the provided bootstrap classes or your own custom classes)

3. > If you have a class, and another inside, and you first set properties to the top(which affect the inner) and then you drill in and set different properties to the inner, will it override the outer ?

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if the parent element has styles and the child element has conflicting styles, will the child element override the parent styles. Yes, styles on the child element will override properties that were inherited.

There are a couple of reasons your `nav-item` class may not be overriding bootstrap's `nav-item`. If bootstrap styles are loaded after your custom styles, the bootstrap class has precedence. Another reason may be the bootstrap class has a more specific selector such as `.navbar-nav > .nav-item` in which case it would have precedence over your less specific selector. Here is a good [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/7176268) over css precedence.

Comment: Thanks so much, you made some order for me. So if I want to be able to override any framework, why not just include my css after the framework so I can override anything as I want ?

Comment: @Curnelious when you have 2 classes with the same name, the class that was defined last takes precedence. So you want to load your custom styles after you load the framework styles.

Comment: and is it a good practice to do so? so I can be the last the edit everything ?

Comment: @Curnelious yes this is good practise and also intended this way, the last one can override everything :). However there is one exception you can't override inline styles marked with !important via selectors. But be aware that you should prevent !important if you can and don't have an specific intention to do so.

Answer (score 1):

1. Think about the concept of **grouping classes**. You can, for instance, change the color of several classes at once, matching a pattern like "navbar". Or apply event listeners to a group to tasks such as animate stuff or programming interactive JS actions.
2. Most modern browser rendering engines support displaying these properties for the set class name in arguments. Look up documentation on the web framework you're developing your web project.
3. From [Mozilla Developers Network's CSS documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple declarations. As per CSS rules, directly targeted elements will always take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Using a name for a class let you set properties in CSS with this name, if so, why some classes gets multiple names- like this one above ?

It gives more granular control over styling and allows certain classes to be used for multiple different elements. For instance, there could be a class called "red-text" that changes the font color that could be added paragraphs, divs, list items etc. Without multiple classes the CSS would need to contain several classes that are nearly identical, except with another line that sets the font color to red (e.g, "p.normal-paragraph" and "normal-paragraph-red").

> 2. If a class has multiple names, how do you set its CSS properties, by which name?

You can use any one of the classes to set its CSS properties, but a couple things worth noting:

1. The class you choose *might* be used by other elements that you don't want to modify, so look out for that.
2. The CSS rules will be applied in sequential order, so if you make a rule for one class (say "font-size:16px") but the element has another class further down the stylesheet that has a different rule for that same property ("font-size:11px") your new rule will be ignored.

> 3. If you have a class, and another inside, and you first set properties to the top(which affect the inner) and then you drill in and set different properties to the inner, will it override the outer?

Yes. Elements will inherit styles from their parents but if a property is changed at a more specific level (in this case the child element) it will use that style instead. Specificity is an important aspect of CSS (this is what makes them "cascading"), and the more specific selector will always trump a less specific selector.