# how edit or disable width in owl-item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

how can to edit or disable width "owl-item" in owl carousel?

my Meaning inside the photo :
[image]

I acted through

( style.css > .owl-item { width : 80px;}  ) , but did not work

Comment: could you pls share a simplified snippet  in the question?

Comment: all source in https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override the div's width in style.css -> change it as below,

```
.owl-item { width : 80px !important; }
```

!important -> Specified style Will be applied to the css elements irrespective of the style being mentioned in the element.

If you want to know how it get applied just have a look in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since the width of the owl carolusel container is dynamically created based on width of the items, setting an `!important` via css will create a large right padding issue due to width calculated from owl via their inline declaration opposed to your css declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the stagePadding option, https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html, this will prevent padding issues with other items on carousel

```
(document).ready(function(){
 $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  nav:true,
  stagePadding: 90,
   .......
```