# How to change inline code color in mkdocs?

Tags: markdown

I am using mkdocs to create a static documentation, and I am using the rtd-dropdown theme. Does anyone know how to change the color of inline code using css for mkdocs?

Comment: Please include what you have tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: I have used: code {
 color: #C70039;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

Comment: I suspect the issue is related to CSS order of precedence. If you use your browser's "inspect" tool, you should find that a rule defined in the theme is overriding your custom rule. See [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25105736/866026) for details.

Answer (score 1):

When your site has rendered in your browser you can:

1. **Right-click on an inline code element on the page**
2. **Choose "Inspect Element" (Firefox) or "Inspect" (Chrome)**
   This will open the inspect tool where you can view the CSS that has been applied to each element on the site. Make sure the inspector sits on a `<code></code>` line.
3. **Find the entry that says `color`**
4. **Find the CSS selector that has rendered the color**

In my case, the CSS selector is `.md-typeset code`.

This means that if I want my inline code text color to be `red`, I can put the following in my `.css` file:

```
.md-typeset p > code {
  color: red;
}
```

Note that `p > code` means "all code inside p-tags", which selects inline code. Neglecting the `p >` might result in code blocks being affected by the css as well. This is likely not what is desired.

You can of course use this to change other attributes like `background-color`, `font-family`, etc. as well.

I'm running MkDocs v1.1.2 with the [Material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/) theme.