# an external style sheet should override all style sheets and internal css

Tags: css

I am using external style sheet more than one and internal css and also bootstrap predefined stylesheet. Now the problem is, I need 1 external style sheet would override all style sheets,internal css and inline css. how can i success it

Comment: Load it last...

Answer (score 0):

You must use "!important" for your properties to override all styles

```
p {
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is precedence to css styling methods. Inline styles takes precedence over internal css (using `<style></style>` tags) and external css (using `<link />` tag).

To force properties use `!important` keyword after your property value.

Example:
***external.css***

```
.home-page {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

PS: Check this question for more info:

[What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add/import external css which should override all the styles at the bottom. First add/import bootstrap, then add/import other css files, then your css file which should override others.

When Adding/Importing css files, order is important. The file you add/import at last will override the previous styles.

If something doesn't work as you expected, then give them `important` like this

```
h1 {
    font-size: 25px !important;
}
```

In-line css rules always take precedence than other css rules/styles. In that case, you need to mark your rules with `!important` keyword.

There are several rules ( applied in this order ) :

1. inline css ( html style attribute ) overrides css rules in style tag and css file
2. a more specific selector takes precedence over a less specific one
3. rules that appear later in the code override earlier rules if both have the same specificity.
4. A css rule with !important always takes precedence.

[Sourec: Details about precedence and css specificity is talked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)