# CSS in the end of the page doesn't affect all of it

Tags: html, css, facebook

I added this code right before the end of the body tag in the facebook.com page (not logged in):

```
<style>
  * {
    font-family: Times New Roman !important
  }
</style>
```

But some text of the website (including "Connect with friends and the
world around you on Facebook.") didn't change. Why?

Comment: set font-family with * is wrong. you have to set it to tags like <p> or class

Comment: @MajidAzarniush there is nothing wrong in setting font-family to *all* the elements.

Comment: it change all element's fonts like icons

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important` may not always work as expected. You also need to check the element level CSS as well. This is in accordance with the [order of precedence for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css).

See the example below which shows how precedence works in CSS.

```css
* {
  font-family: Times New Roman !important;
  color: red !important;
}

.different {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is para 1
</p>

<p class="different">
  This is para 2
</p>
```

Comment: The style which overrides mine is not element-level. It is applied to `._3ma` class.

Answer (score -3):

You should add your style tag after the `<head>`.