# My navbar disappears when I use jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I have a jQuery problem.

So when I'm using the PC version of my website and I click in navbar items (which is `#menu-two .items` in my HTML code), the navbar menu disappears.

I have some media queries to readjust the navbar menu and in this media queries I want the navbar (which is .hide) to hide when I click on the navbar items, in this case tablet and mobile version.

It seems that the computer version cannot be separated from these two versions in this case and hides the `#menu-two` too.

```js
 
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
$('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
$('#menu-two').toggleClass('hide')
$('.hide').fadeToggle()
}) 

$('.active').on('click', function() {
    $('.toggle').fadeToggle()
})

$('.item').on('click', function() {
      $('.hide').fadeToggle()
})
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black
}

#menu-two {
  display: flex;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
  #menu-two {
    display: none;
  }
  .hide {
    background-color: rgb(253, 236, 214);
    opacity: 0.95;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .options {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%
  }
  .toggle {
    display: initial;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    transform: translate(-10px);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle span {
    position: relative;
    width: 36px;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .toggle span:nth-child(1) {
    transform-origin: left;
  }
  .toggle span:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  .toggle span:nth-child(3) {
    transform-origin: left;
  }
  .toggle.active span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left: 2px;
  }
  .toggle.active span:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    right: 3px;
  }
  .toggle.active span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-one">
  <div class="toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<ul id="menu-two" class="hide">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="./prototype.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item" id="proj">
    <a href="./exp.html">Projects</a>
  </li>
  <li class="options">
    <a href="./Atower.html">A-Tower</a>
  </li>
  <li class="options">
    <a href="./muda.html">Muda</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#About-Me">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is when I use this jQuery code, it is acting not only in my media queries, but outside of it too, so my navbar is hidden in PC version even though a I had a `display: none` in `.hide` class.

What should I do?

Comment: could you provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery's `fadeToggle` adds styles inline to an element, [which takes precedence over stylesheet styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css). That's why your media queries are being ignored. If you want to fade out only within certain media queries, you can instead toggle a class and add the relevant styles to that class. For example:

JS

```
$('.item').on('click', function() {
    $('.hide').toggleClass('hidden');
    ...
```

CSS

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
  .hide {
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }

  .hide.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

If you need to have the element set to `display: none` (for example, so that it doesn't push other elements down) you can have a `setTimeout` in your jQuery code in order to set the element to be hidden after an animation has been completed, or displayed before an animation starts again.

Comment: Hi Oliver!

How can I display .hide and .toggle again after this event?

because after this event I tried to click on my icon menu that is now an X and nothing happens because .hidden is blocking it correct?

Comment: I have made a fiddle - does this do what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/emqpvafk/
Basically, I have remove the jQuery showing/hiding the list, and instead adds/removes a class that makes the list visible or not

Comment: My primary code does what I want for my media queries, the problem is when width is bigger than 1210px,  I click on items and then they simply disappear.

Comment: OK, I see that now. You have a `fadeToggle` call on the links when they are clicked. I have removed that now here: https://jsfiddle.net/8kcx7ft6/ - does that solve your issue?