# Why is the whole navigation div magenta instead of blue when it is hovered?

Tags: html, css

does use id or class to select the element matter? The whole navigation div should be blue when it is hovered since it is applied after the magenta.

```css
.navigation {
  color: salmon;
  height: 100px;
}

#navigation:hover {
  color: magenta;
}

.navigation:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
  <div id="navigation" class="navigation">I am navigation text!
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, what's the point in asking this? Why not just one selector, and one `:hover` selection?

Comment: have a look into [order of precedence for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Comment: Yes it matters, this is called *CSS specificity*. You can read up more here: https://marksheet.io/css-priority.html

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this resource: [Calculating CSS Specificity Value](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/#article-header-id-0)

> ... Simply using the class name by itself had a lower specificity value and was trumped by the other selector which targeted the unordered list with the ID value. The important words in that sentence were class and ID. CSS applies vastly different specificity weights to classes and IDs. In fact, an ID has infinitely more specificity value! That is, no amount of classes alone can outweigh an ID.

In summary, `ID` is more specific than `Class`, therefore an element with the same CSS attribute being specified (e.g. `color`) within an `ID` and `Class` will have the value of the `ID` attribute specification, not the `Class` specification.

`Inline` styles are more specific yet again, and will trump an `ID` style.

[image]

As sourced from: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/#article-header-id-0