# formgroup label showing in uppercase but I want it to be titlecase

Tags: html, css, angular, label

I have the following angular template. I noticed that even when the labels are in titlecase when the page is rendered the labels are converted to uppercase and I don't like it.  So I decided to use the titlecase pipe and surround the label text with single quotes. However, the labels are still in uppercase (image attached for reference)

I guess this is something that should be straightforward but I don't know how to make it work.
Any ideas?

```
<form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(updateForm.value)">
    <div>
        <label for="total">
          {{'Total' | titlecase}}
        </label>
        <input id="total" type="text" formControlName="total">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="supporters">
          {{'Number of supporters' | titlecase}}
        </label>
        <input id="supporters" type="text" formControlName="supporters">
      </div>      
    <button class="button" type="submit">Save</button>

  </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems just a css issue no? If your labels are already properly cased, a pipe seems a bit overkill..?

Comment: There is no inbuilt pipe called titlecase in angular.

Comment: @Prince I think there is, here is the documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe

Comment: @MikeOne I think the same. However, without the pipe it is still showing up with uppercase even when the labels are already properly cased as you mentioned.

Comment: @Annie it seems to be an issue with your css. Can upload this component to https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: Yep. There probably is a css style like label {text-transform: uppercase} somewhere.. This is not an Angular issue.

Comment: You were right guys! It was a css issue. While I was setting up the component in stackblitz.com as @GermanQuinteros suggested I noticed that it was rendered correctly. https://angular-kk74fp.stackblitz.io/actualizar
My component did not have any css style that is why I discarded it but it was inheriting the style from the styles.css file that I did not import in the stackblitz project. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with your CSS.

Probably, you are using a library or css file that for the `<label>` it setting the property `text-transform: uppercase;`.

You can try overriding that with a custom css rules like:

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(updateForm.value)">
    <div>
        <label class="custom-label-title" for="total">
          {{'Total'}}
        </label>
        <input id="total" type="text" formControlName="total">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label  class="custom-label-title" for="supporters">
          {{'Number of supporters' }}
        </label>
        <input id="supporters" type="text" formControlName="supporters">
      </div>      
    <button class="button" type="submit">Save</button>

  </form>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-label-title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Just in case that it doesn't work (only for test purpose) add `!important`:

**CSS**

```
.custom-label-title {
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
}
```

Because it can be happening that the other CSS rules have bigger precedence:

[What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Comment: Thanks German! You were right, it was a css issue. I added the custom-label-title class that you suggested and at the end I had to add the !important to force using this style over the ones that as you said might have higher precedence.