# Ctrl+5F shows me the two different types of display

Tags: browser-cache

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU1a8.png)

I'm currently working on a website.

Attached is the part of the website that I can watch on my computer monitor.

Changed Display below is the what I want.

However, if I keep hitting 'ctrl+f5', the screen shows me either unchanged display or changed display.

I have no idea why it shows me two different types of screen.

As far as I know, 'ctrl+f5' deletes the cache and updates data but it is not for me.

Ridiculously, If I keep hitting 'f5', I can only have the changed display as I want.

I guess I have a problem on css because I get an error message: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:8090/asset/css/sub.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE.

Does anyone know the keys on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info here for anyone to tell you how to fix your problem with any amount of certainty.

What do you mean by changed display? Just the website looking different? Or a different debug preview (like scaling your website down to a phone's screen size)?

If it looks different, that might just have to do with caching.
The difference between `CTRL + F5` and just `F5` is that `CTRL + F5` doesn't use your browser's cache, instead fetching everything fresh from the server, whereas just `F5` uses your browser's cache. Your browser generally keeps track of when it cached things and will automatically fetch data anew if the time of caching was too long ago.

The former generally takes longer to load, naturally, which might be why the website looks different, at least until everything has been loaded.

Other than that, CSS gets a little weird sometimes, applying styles in a weird order. This generally has to do with the order in which, and where in your HTML document you actually load your stylesheets. Generally, loading all of them in the head of the document is a good idea. Complete redefinitions of styles in separate stylesheets can get very weird, even if it should follow normal precedence ([Thread on CSS precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css))

Though, again, you'll have to elaborate on your problem further, maybe provide some screenshots, for anyone to be able to definitively help you.

Comment: Thank you for your kind rely, could you check the revised question with a picture again?