# How to override TailwindCSS utility classes in components without using !important option?

Tags: components, vue-component, tailwind-css

For example, say you have a component like this (using VueJS as an example):

```html
<!-- Container.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="px-5">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

And you want to override the `px-5` with `px-10` class when you actually call it, like this:

```html
<template>
  <Container class="px-10">
<template>
```

The above doesn't work because px-5 was written first, already setting that property... so px-5 wins by default.

I don't want to write `!px-10` because I've been heard from various sources that using `!important` tags is not a good practice.

How can I make the above example work without using !important?

Comment: Same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66572968/design-system-styles-override-using-tailwindcss/76766246#76766246)

Answer (score 0):

From [my own research](https://discord.com/channels/486935104384532500/486935104384532502/1199647707367743560), it seems like [tailwind-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) is the best solution so far.

How to use it (*using Vue 3*):

```js
<template>
  <div :class="twMerge('px-5', $attrs.class')">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'
</script>
```