# Styling hyperlink in CSS class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the hyperlink colour property in CSS by using jQuery `.toggleClass`. Here is what I mean:

The CSS class with [a] (hyperlink) in which I want to change the colour

```
.navigation a { color: black;}
```

The colour I want to change to:

```
.color-change-to-white-text {
   color: white;}
```

jQuery I wrote, but it does not work:

```
$('a.navigation').toggleClass("color-change-to-white-text");
```

Is there any way to do this kind of styling?

Comment: `a.navigation` is the wrong selector - `.navigation a`!!

Comment: Your css is `.navigation a` but your selector is `a.navigation` - these are not the same thing.  If you include the HTML we can tell you which is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Comment: Your issue is css precedence.   `.navigation a` takes precedence of `.white` so will always use those styles, regardless of whether you add the class using jquery or directly.  See here https://jsfiddle.net/76jh3edg/ for an example and the linked answer for more details.

Comment: You are all right friends. I have done this the way I have wrote it above, as `.navigation a` wasn't working for me either, doesn't know why.

Answer (score 0):

`.toggleclass` doesn't change classes: it toggles them, so if you want to change an element's class, you could use the jQuery `$(/* id */).attr("class", "color-change-to-white-text")`. If you prefer pure Javascript, you can use `document.getElementById(/* id */).setAttribute("class", "color-change-to-white-text").`

Comment: `.toggleClass` is fine here - otherwise it would be `.addClass` - you would very unlikely want to use `.attr("class"` in jquery.  OPs issue is with the selector they are using, not how they are changing the class.

Comment: Correction, OPs issue is *also* caused by css precedence (and the selector is wrong...)

Comment: I have used the `.toggleClass` as I want to change the colours back and fourth. It is easier (I could be wrong here) that way.