# @aws-amplify/ui-react how to customize UI if my project uses SASS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm extending a Next.js (React) project that was built by someone else, which uses .scss files (SASS) for styling. This is the project in question https://github.com/codebushi/nextjs-starter-dimension

Now I'm adding an authentication flow to the project using `@aws-amplify/ui-react`. Everything works fine, but I want to customize the UI style. I've found in the documentation that I can do that through `:root` in globals.css, as so:

```
:root {
  --amplify-primary-color: #ff6347;
  --amplify-primary-tint: #ff7359;
  --amplify-primary-shade: #e0573e;
}
```

Documentation here: https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/customization/theming/q/framework/react

I know pretty much nothing about SASS except the basics. How would I do the equivalent of setting those variables in `:root`?

**Edit with more details**

This is my `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    )
    return config
  }
}
```

This is my authentication page where the Amplify elements are defined:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components';
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifyAuthContainer, AmplifySignUp, AmplifySignIn, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import Router from 'next/router'

const Auth = (props) => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
      return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
          setAuthState(nextAuthState);
          setUser(authData);
          //console.log(`authData: ${JSON.stringify(authData, null, 2)}`);
      });
  }, []);

  if (authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user) {
    Router.push('https://mywebsite')
    return <p>Redirecting...</p>
  }

  return (
    <AmplifyAuthContainer>
        <AmplifyAuthenticator usernameAlias="email">
          <AmplifySignUp
            slot="sign-up"
            usernameAlias="email"
            formFields={[
              {
                type: "email",
                label: "Email Address *",
                placeholder: "Enter your email address",
                inputProps: { required: true },
              },
              {
                type: "password",
                label: "Password *",
                placeholder: "Enter your password",
                inputProps: { required: true },
              },
            ]} 
          />
          <AmplifySignIn slot="sign-in" usernameAlias="email" />
        </AmplifyAuthenticator>
    </AmplifyAuthContainer>
  );
}

export default Auth;
```

As per the answer below from Sean W, I've already tried creating an _app.js with:

```
import '../styles/global.scss'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default App;
```

with `global.scss`:

```
:root {
  --amplify-primary-color: #ff6347;
  --amplify-primary-tint: #ff7359;
  --amplify-primary-shade: #e0573e;
}
```

But the CSS variables don't seem to be replaced.

Comment: You can simply use `:root` and CSS variables directly with Sass.

Comment: @juliomalves I've been reading about that, and here they give an example: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars

I've attempted to create an scss file with the `:root` configuration, but nothing seems to change (the variables I change in root just remain the same they were)

Answer (score 1):

Include the styles in your pages. The easiest way is to create a new SCSS file and include it in a custom [_app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

By default, [Next supports SASS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support) - you only need to install the sass npm package and likely do not need a custom next.config.  This could be one of your problems.

file - global.scss -

```
:root{
  --amplify-primary-color: #ff6347;
  --amplify-primary-shade: #e0573e;
}

//scoped & redeclared to an element with id #__next
:root #__next {
  --amplify-primary-color: #ff6347;
  --amplify-primary-shade: #e0573e;
}
```

*Amplify could also be setting setting styles after you have already defined them for the :root - if this is the case you will need to scope your custom styles to take precedence over the default Amplify CSS variables. To do this - [redeclare them](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables_overriding.asp) in a CSS rule that is more specific than `:root` like the example above - keeping [order of precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/15304814) in mind*

Amplify also lets you [directly target components](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/customization/customizing-css/q/framework/react).

```
amplify-authenticator {
  --amplify-primary-color: #ff6347;
  background: var(--amplify-primary-color);
  padding: 5px;
}

// scoped & redeclared 
:root #__next amplify-sign-in{
  --amplify-primary-color: #ff6347;
}
```

The amplify elements that can be targeted are

- amplify-authenticator
- amplify-sign-in
- amplify-confirm-sign-in
- amplify-sign-up
- amplify-confirm-sign-up
- amplify-forgot-password
- amplify-require-new-password
- amplify-verify-contact
- amplify-totp-setup

import your file - pages/_app.js

```
import 'path/to/global.scss';
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => <Component {...pageProps} />;
export default App;
```

Comment: I've tried this, but those variables don't seem to be replaced. When I check the styles in the element inspector, `--amplify-primary-color` for example, keeps the default value of `#ff9900`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. (I've edited my question to include some more details)

Answer (score 0):

Global variables (the equivalent of `:root` variables) can be created simply with this line.

```
$color = #c0ff33 !important;
```

The content can be anything that is available in css and partially sass.
For large projects, creating a `variables.scss` file and including in it all these variable declarations can be truly helpful for changing multiple variables at once. To include this file, just do `@import "./variables.scss"` at the top of your file.

Hope this helps! Good luck in your *sassy* endeavors!