# Custom theme antd design not working with input control

Tags: javascript, antd

I'm trying to custom theme of antd but I have a trouble when I customizing like below

[image]

This trouble appears in only input control, for another control

[image]

So now I need take global.less above index.less. Do you have any ideas for me? Thanks!

Comment: You should read up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)