# How to realize that after clicking on an element through CSS, it will not be affected by hover?

Tags: css

I want to ask you a CSS question. My English is not good, but I try to express it completely!
Today I hope to change the background to red after clicking, and not to have the hover effect (now hover will turn yellow in the past).
If I don’t use javascript and jquery and only use CSS, how can I do it?

Thank you all for watching in advance, I really need your help!

ex

```js
$('.button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
})
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">123</div>
<div class="button">123</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you require you need to make the `.red` selector more specific, so that it cannot be overridden by the `:hover` state.

In this case you can achieve it by preceding it with `.button`

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
})
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">123</div>
<div class="button">123</div>
```

One thing to note is that people often use, or are suggested to use, the `!important` flag in cases like this, to override styles. However this is not a good approach as it means that the style which had the flag applied cannot as easily be overridden through specificity. As such maintenance and debugging can become much harder.

For more information on CSS selector specificity, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/519413) on the subject.

Comment: Thank you, I really need to improve my CSS at the moment!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

There's a CSS selector known `:active` this part of CSS activates when any element is clicked. Read more about it on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp).

Comment: Using `:active` here won't prevent the `:hover` style from being applied, as the OP is asking for. Also, please don't use W3Schools. Their articles are usually very outdated and often just plain wrong. As such they should not be relied upon, especially by beginners. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) is a far more up to date and comprehensive resoure.