# How to resolve Tailwind and Bootstrap conflicts in an Angular project

Tags: css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS and Bootstrap (ngx-bootstrap) in the same Angular project. For the most part, they play along nicely. However, when it comes to padding and margins, they fight like siblings. I want to use Tailwind for padding because it is consistent. For example, the class `p-X` is X times 0.25 rem but with bootstrap, it is all over the place. The annoying thing is that Bootstrap puts `!important` everywhere.

`utilities.css` comes from Tailwind and `_spacing.scss` comes from Bootstrap.

[image: padding 3]

[image: padding 4]

[image: padding 5]

Is there a convenient way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice to avoid naming conflicts with Tailwind utility classes is using [`prefix` option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) on your [`tailwind.config.js`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration) file.

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

But if you want only to put `!important` rule for Tailwind classes, and you have already control the order of css code (tailwind classes are the last), you can set the [`important` option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important) to true on the tailwind config file.

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

Make sur to not override tailwind classes when you're choosing to set the `important` option only, see [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Answer (score 5):

When you use both **bootstrap** and **tailwind-css** at the same time, you will face naming conflicts which will lead to undefined behavior ,

There are two ways to overcome .

- First way is to solve is by using `prefix option` in your
  `tailwind.config.css` file

  ```
   // tailwind.config.js
      module.exports = {
         prefix: 'tw-',
      }
  ```

So now you can use the prefix `tw-` before the class name of tailwind-css which wont break any of your existing styles.

- If you are facing problem in changing of the overall changes caused by adding `tailwind-css` to the existing `bootstrap` project setting off the `preflight` of tailwind-css would be preferred.

Preflight by default in their projects which is an opinionated set of base styles.

And this is build on top of modern-normalize

And Tailwind automatically injects these styles in `@tailwind base`.

So to overcome this .Remove `@tailwind base` from the css file or Add `preflight: false,`

```
module.exports = {
   corePlugins: {
      preflight: false,
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prefix, with the latest update of Tailwind you can do that with the CDN as well.

Please refer to this link: https://developerwings.com/tailwind-and-bootstrap-together/