# Tailwind css mobile first overwrites other media queries and classes

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, css-specificity

In an angular app (^13.*), I've installed and initialized tailwindcss via

```
> npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
> npx tailwindcss init
```

as per their own documentation.

At first, I had issues with the default mobile-first classes (like: `p-2 mb-3` etc.), that they have always overwritten other media queries, for example, if I had a `p-2 md:p-3`, in the browser devtools, I would always see the `md:p-3` crossed out, **regardless of screen width**.

So I thought that it might have to with ***specificity*** so in tailwind.config.js I set the important property to true

```
module.exports = {
   important: true,
   ...
}
```

Although that solved the media query issue, now I have an issue with ***border*** for example, if I have `border border-blue-500`, the original `border` would overwrite the border color since `border` has a default color of `#dee2e6` so `border-blue-500` would have no effect at all.

I assume it has to do with the order in which tailwindcss applies the css classes.

I tried to reinstall tailwindcss but was no help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Tailwind and Bootstrap conflicts in an Angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718228/how-to-resolve-tailwind-and-bootstrap-conflicts-in-an-angular-project)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the cause of this issue was due to some default styling imported in styles.scss that overwrote tailwindcss classes, by removing that specific import, the issue was resolved.

I might have broken a lot more things now, but to answer this question, this was the solution

Comment: To resolve issue with conflicts it's good practice to use a prefix for all your angular classes [check out this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72580574/20501520)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add in that the actual fix for me was adding what you had Israel.  By adding in the important: true into the module.exports of the tailwind.config.js file, my styling issues were fixed.

```
module.exports = {important: true, ...}
```