# Tailwind CSS breaking existing styles

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, tailwind-css

When I added Tailwind to my React project, it breaks existing styles.

I was hoping to just use Tailwind classes (like `mb-3`) for shortcuts.
I didn't expect it to overwrite existing styles, like changing button background to transparent.

Am I doing it wrong? Or does Tailwind overwrite styles on purpose?

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm talking about: (which comes from `node_modules\tailwindcss\src\css\preflight.css`)
[image]

The issue goes away when I exclude base, i.e:

```
//@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**EDIT 2:**

Found the **[solution](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight)**!

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

Comment: What were you  working on ? Bootstrap ? or plain css ? or any other before using tailwind css

Comment: I've got Bootstrap, but does it matter? I was wondering why Tailwind is changing my buttons to transparent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use both **bootstrap** and **tailwind-css** at the same time, you will face naming conflicts which will lead to undefined behavior ,

To avoid this, use the [prefix option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) in your `tailwind.config.js` file

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

So now you can use the prefix `tw-` before the class name of tailwind-css which wont break any of your existing styles.

**Note** if you want tailwind classes to get more precedence than any other css styles , you can set the [important option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important) to true on `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

To understand the css precedence follow this [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

**Extended answer**:

Thanks to Aximili ,

Tailwind-Css implements **Preflight** by default in their projects which is an opinionated set of base styles.

And this is build on top of **modern-normalize**

And Tailwind automatically injects these styles in `@tailwind base`.

So to overcome this .Remove `@tailwind base` from the css file or Add `preflight: false,`

```
module.exports = {
   corePlugins: {
      preflight: false,
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Krishna! Unfortunately I am already using a lot of Tailwind classes everywhere. But excluding base might fix it (although I'm not sure if any side effect). See my EDIT on the question.

Comment: Thanks Aximili for letting me know the concept ! I made some changes in my answer giving you the credits in Extended answer section to complete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

An now you can use both bootstrap and tailwind but you will have to use `tw-` before tailwind classes such as `tw-mb-2`, `tw-text-right` etc.

while you still can use bootstrap normally. The classes won't conflict anymore.

I will not recommend using important in `tailwind.config.css` because you still might want to use the bootstrap at some location so the prefix is the best bet here.