# Make margin style to mat-slide-toggle-bar element

Tags: html, angular, sass

I want to do a margin style for `mat-slide-toggle-bar` which is in a specific parent element `mat-slide-toggle` with class name `parent-element`.

Here my Html:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c397=""
    class="parent-element mat-slide-toggle parent-element mat-accent mat-checked mat-disabled ng-untouched ng-pristine"
    ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" id="mat-slide-toggle-1"><label class="mat-slide-toggle-label"
        for="mat-slide-toggle-1-input">
        <span class="mat-slide-toggle-bar">
            <input type="checkbox" role="switch" class="mat-slide-toggle-input cdk-visually-hidden"
                id="mat-slide-toggle-1-input" tabindex="-1" disabled="" aria-checked="true">
            <span class="mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container">
                <span class="mat-slide-toggle-thumb"></span>
                <span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-slide-toggle-ripple mat-focus-indicator"
                    ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]" ng-reflect-disabled="true" ng-reflect-centered="true"
                    ng-reflect-radius="20" ng-reflect-animation="[object Object]">
                    <span class="mat-ripple-element mat-slide-toggle-persistent-ripple"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="mat-slide-toggle-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span> text</span></label>
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

What I did in style file but dosn't work :

```css
.parent-element .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  margin-left: 80px;
}}}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: @André How ?  the mat-slide-toggle-bar is generated in Dom object but in my html I have only that

Comment: You have references to mat-slide-toggle-bar and mat-slide-toggle-label, this is not part of your code and there's no way to help you without knowing how they are build.

Comment: @André I modified html code in question

Comment: Your approach is correct, did you also tried `.mat-slide-toggle-bar {margin-left: 80px;}` (without specific parents)? You should check your code in the browser inspector to see what might be overwriting it or maybe not importing correctly.

Comment: @André I did it and in inspector I have  margin-left: 80px; not applied with a ligne --------- style, I don't know what we call that in css, how to know what overwriting it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250062/discussion-between-andre-and-coder-meca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by this code in the scss of my parent component :

```css
.parent-element .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.mat-slide-toggle-bar {margin-left: 80px !important;}
```

`!important` will take precedence over most other rules.

The first answer to the linked question gives more details about it:
[What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Comment: dosn't work also with not important