# How to target the children selector under a parent (which it has the same class to the parent-parent selector) without using inline css?

Tags: css

```
<section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Nav Bar -->

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

<styles.css>

```
/* Containers */

.container-fluid {
    padding: 7% 15%;
}

/* Navigation Bar */

#navbar .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

/* Title Section */

#title .container-fluid {
    padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}
```

I want to remain the .container-fluid {padding: 7% 15%} because it is applied to all the other sections of the website.

Only for the Navigation bar, I want to make different padding to that container, I have tried the following combined selectors, however they didn't work.

```
    #navbar .container-fluid 
    .navbar .container-fluid
```

It only works if I add inline css, what if external css? How do to it?

Thank you.

Comment: Not able to understand whare you want to achieve. There is confusion that for which element you want to apply what padding.

Comment: you can give extra class to navbar container and it will work. what is issue then?

Comment: Apologize for the confusion, I want to apply padding: 0 0 4.5 rem to #navbar .container-fluid, but it didn't work

Comment: see here https://jsfiddle.net/ubeaw3kL/ i have added color to both class and can see they are applying different different. Use different name.

Comment: and if you want same class then see this https://jsfiddle.net/ubeaw3kL/1/

Comment: if I change the name to become container-fluid1, the alignment of nav-item runs, since container-fluid is under bootstrap, so I couldn't change the name right?

Comment: In your CSS rule `#title .container-fluid { padding: 3% 15% 7%; }` being last defined overrides all the above as `#title` it is the main parent of a `.container-fluid` references. The rule's current effect: *all `.container-fluid` inside `#title` will use `padding: 3% 15% 7%;`*

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
/* Navigation Bar */

.container-fluid {
   padding: 7% 15%;
}

/* Title Section */

#title .container-fluid {
   padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}

#navbar .container-fluid {
   padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}
```

You can also fix this by adding `!important` at the end like this:

```
#navbar .container-fluid {
   padding: 0 0 4.5rem !important;
}
```

But I don't recommend it.

More about css order can you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/14118567).

Comment: I have the changed the sequence as what you did, not sure why it still didn't work. But, by adding `!important` , it works, thanks!!

Comment: @PangZiYing I updated the post so you don't need `!important` if you want.

Comment: Got it! Appreciate it! Now all make sense to me and it works for both ways :)