# Selectors and properties

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wrote the below html which contains a container and a box class. The box class has a `p` tag as a child containing with some text.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container .box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(227, 243, 199);
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, mollitia.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My question is :**

Why the box class element is taking properties from `.container .box` and not from `.box` ?

[image]

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 2):

Because the `.container .box` selector is more specific than `.box`.

You can read more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Also, you can check in DevTools by hovering CSS selectors in the `Styles` panel:

[image]

[image]

If you want the styles from `.box` to take precedence over those in `.container .box`, you have two options:

Add one or more additional classes to the selector (second column in the Specificity calculation).

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container .box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(227, 243, 199);
}

.box.coral {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box coral">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, mollitia.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that if you only add one additional class, the specificity in both `.container .box` and `.box.coral` (in my example below) is the same (`(0,2,0)`), so the one that come latter takes precedence.

Alternatively, a single `ID` selector will have a higher specificity (`(1,0,0)`):

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container .box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(227, 243, 199);
}

#coralBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="coralBox" class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, mollitia.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS if you define two selectors with the same properties, the more specific selector will be prioritize. In your case `.container .box` is more specific dans `.box`.
I recommend you the answers of this question : [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css) and this article [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score -2):

Either way, the **.box** class will take the properties of the **parent class**.Try adding `<span></span>`.

You can read more about this at https://ricardometring.com/css-class-inside-other-class.