# How to change link color in div class?

Tags: html, css

I have some links in my div class however, I am unable to change the color of the link.

I've tried removing the div class, but I won't be able to align my links.

```css
#link {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id='link' style="text-align:center">

  <a id='left' href="how.html">How to Avoid Fighting</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='center' href="why.html">Why You Should Not Fight</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='right' href="Ways.html">Ways to Fight</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor elements have default color, so you need a more specific selector to change it.

[What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Protips: Use classes for your CSS whenever possible so it's reusable. Don't use inline styles, especially when you already have a stylesheet. It makes for messy and less readable markup.

```css
#link, #link a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id='link' style="text-align:center">
  <a id='left' href="how.html">How to Avoid Fighting</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='center' href="why.html">Why You Should Not Fight</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='right' href="Ways.html">Ways to Fight</a>
</div>
```