# CSS button:disabled doesn't apply to buttons previously styled by id

Tags: html, css, button, disabled-control

In both Chrome and Firefox on Windows I have come across this behavior. Button colors are styled by id and by class, then I use a global `button:disabled` rule to set that color to gray. All the buttons whose non-disabled color is set via a class-based rule are properly styled when disabled, but those styled by an id-based rule are unaffected by the `button:disabled`.

```css
button {
  font-size:2rem;
  width:3rem;
}
#a { 
  color:red; 
}
.b {
  color:green;
}
#c, #d {
  color:blue; 
}
button:disabled, #c:disabled {
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<button id="a" class="a" disabled>A</button>
<button id="b" class="b" disabled>B</button>
<button id="c" class="c" disabled>C</button>
<button id="d" class="d">D</button>
```

Button A, styled by id, has red text in spite of the global `button:disabled` rule.

Button B, styled by class, is properly styled by the `button:disabled` rule.

Button C is properly styled, but it requires a separate `#c:disabled` rule.

Button D is the only one that is not disabled, for comparison purposes.

Is this a feature or a bug? If it's a feature, can someone please explain it? I would automatically consider it a bug if it weren't for the fact that the behavior is consistent across two major browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug.

They are obeying the three column values and comparison rules. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#specifications

In particular

> The selector with the greater value in the ID column wins no matter
> what the values are in the other columns.

In general, the comparison is done by column 1 first, and if there is a winner there the other columns don’t come into it.

Then the second column is considered and likewise if there is a winner, the third column is not considered.

Looking at the selectors used in the question:

An id puts a 1 in the first column.

The class adds a 1 to the second column.

The pseudo class :disabled adds a 1 to the second column.

The type button adds a 1 to the third column.

The #a therefore has a 1 in the first column and this beats anything in the second and third columns, thus that element has color red.

For the #c that will have weight 1-0-0 as well but that will be beaten by the 1-1-0 of the #c:disabled.

Note that the button:disabled is weaker at 0-1-1.

The cascading order only comes into play if there are two selectors with the same weight, then the one that comes afterwards wins.

Comment: OK, I was assuming that the :disabled had more weight, i.e. that it created a whole other entity of sorts where the specificity rules would apply.  It's darned inconvenient, but at least now I understand better how it works.  I had perused that MDN page, but I glossed over the pseudo-class is column 2 part.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, more specific rules override less specific ones. Basically, an **id** selector is more specific than a **class** selector, which is more specific than a **type** selector. [More details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

What I would do is to put the `button:disabled` rule up the top just under the `button` rule, to cater for all buttons without specific styling. Then for any buttons where I want a different color, append `:not(:disabled)` to the selector.

```css
button {
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 3rem;
  color: green;
}

button:disabled {
  color: gray;
}

#a1:not(:disabled), #a2:not(:disabled) { 
  color: red; 
}

.b:not(:disabled) { 
  color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<button id="a1" class="a">A</button>
<button id="b1" class="b">B</button>
<button id="c1" class="c">C</button>
<button id="a2" class="a" disabled>A</button>
<button id="b2" class="b" disabled>B</button>
<button id="c2" class="c" disabled>C</button>
```

Comment: But then why does button B work properly? Class is more specific than type, but `type:disabled` overrides `.class`.  And there is no `:disabled` by anything other than type, so there's nothing to override it, is there?

Comment: Updated my answer. However, I am also puzzled as to why `type:disabled` is overriding `.class`. Bound to be something in the specificity spec which explains it, though.

Comment: Thanks, I see the updated answer, but to me it's six of one = half a dozen of the other. I achieve the same thing by concatenating `, #id:disabled` to `button:disabled`, as in my original snippet. It's even less text that way, without the `not`. I put `button:disabled` after the other rules because order is a factor too, not just specificity.  The less specific rule is later, thus it overrides the previous rules if specificity doesn't interfere. It also doesn't answer my question: why isn't this working? I do not see how specificity is the issue per my previous comment.

Comment: Order is a factor too.  This stackoverflow answer spells out the various types of precedence in CSS rules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/4941356. `button:disabled` is after `.b`, and also there are no other `:disabled` rules, so specificity should not be an issue here. But I just tested my snippet putting `button:disabled` as the first rule and it works the same way, so order is not the issue either.  There is no other specific rule that uses `:disabled`, which is why it should work for button A too.  The real question is: why doesn't button A disable properly?