# css margin left li.class

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post

Should be simple but I cant seem to get it.

I have list item with a class `second`

```
<li :class="second category == 1095 ? 'child' : ''" ;="">
                <a class="child post_no" data-value="3" @click="total += parseInt($el.dataset.value); filterPosts(1095)">Threat Detection, Investigation, and Response (3)</a>
            </li>
```

I want to add margin left to that class.

I have tried

```
 li.second {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using some meta-HTML language like mustache or something? I'm seeing `:class` and `@click`, and a ternary that could be JS or PHP

Comment: When you inspect this in the DOM, does the element not have the expected class?

Comment: And if the element _does_ have the class - then the margin could still get overwritten by another rule with a more specific selector; so check for that as well.

Comment: Open page in Chrome, right click element, choose Inspect, in the Elements box, make sure your element is selected *and* has the expected class - now look in the `Styles` box and find your margin.  If it has a line-through it, then it's not applied and you'll have to look through the *applied* styles to determine what is applied.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/2181514) for css order of precedence.  Here's an example (https://jsfiddle.net/4s21wfht/) where `ul#id li` takes precedence (is applied over `li.class`)

Comment: Thats my normal process, however even though i have written the css li.second its not showing in the inspect tool

Comment: Is the CSS inline with the page or in a file? If the CSS being automatically generated by JS, or is it static (client-side static, I'm not talking about server-side dynamic which doesn't matter). If it is static, when you view source (**not** inspect), do you see the rule?

Comment: Do you have css `li.second a { margin-left: -10px; }`?   Please provide a snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.  See [mcve].  At the very least, the *rendered* HTML

Answer (score -2):

Your CSS selector li.second should indeed target list items with the class "second". However, the issue might be with specificity or cascade in your CSS. Make sure there are no conflicting styles that override the margin-left property. You can try increasing the specificity of your selector to ensure it takes precedence over other styles.

Here's how you can do it:

```
li.second {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 10px !important; /* Use !important to ensure it takes precedence */
}
```

Adding !important ensures that this style will override any conflicting styles applied elsewhere. However, it's generally recommended to use !important sparingly, as it can make your CSS harder to maintain. If possible, try to refactor your CSS to avoid using !important by increasing the specificity of your selectors or restructuring your CSS rules.

Comment: "*will override any conflicting styles applied elsewhere*" - unless those conflicting styles *also* have `!important`  (not sure reason for downvote)

Comment: @James, I don't disagree with anything you say, but could you please add some very strong emphasis to the guidance to use it sparingly? There's a lot of people that just copy-and-paste answers into their code...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).