confused by CSS precedence
I have 2 css rule sets applying to a cell of a table. I thought one set of rules would override the other, but it is picking and choosing some from each. the rules contradict each other.
the html is generated by javascript


const toDoArray = {
  test: true,
}

var toDoElements = "<table style=\"width: 100%;\">";

for (var k in toDoArray) { // Loop through the object
  var trS = "";
  if (toDoArray[k]) {
    trS = `class="taskChecked"`
  }
  toDoElements +=
    `<tr ${trS} id="${k}-tr">
      <td onclick="checkOffToDo('${k}')" id = "${k}-td" border=none > ${k}</td>
      <td onclick="removeToDo('${k}')" class="toDoDeleteButton">&times;</td>     
    </tr>`
}

toDoElements += "</table>";

document.getElementById("toDoList").innerHTML = toDoElements;
#toDoList { width: 200px; font-size: 3rem; }

.taskChecked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: violet;
  color: purple;
  background: orange;
}

.toDoDeleteButton {
  border: none;
  width: 8%;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-decoration-color: aqua;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div id="toDoList"></div>




I found this StackOverflow Answer describing precedence (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841), but this doesn't seem follow it.
If it followed all one, or all the other, I thought I could get it to work right, but now I'm just really confused.
My chief aim is to not give it a line through. the rest of the colors and stuff are me testing options trying to figure out what's going on, and why its not working.
This is in Chrome.

What exactly are the applied rules you don't expect?

Some css properties are inherited by child elements. So, the text-decoration from the tr element affects the td element.

@qrsngky that is true, but the child has its own rule. This may be one of those really weird things about how table styles work.

@Pointy - nah, this is about how text-decoration propagates and accumulates.

I can reproduce a similar thing with div > div: the child cannot 'cancel' the text-decoration from the parent.
However, using display:inline-block on the child somehow makes it "cancelable". This is not an option for a table cell, though.

@Alohci yea I'm sure it is, but the way the DOM inspector shows the styles is pretty suspect, as the <td> (with only a text node) has an explicit text-decoration style, and the browser shows it as being active, but it clearly does not work.

Anybody who actually gets this should add a better answer than mine :) e: oh it's right there in the MDN documentation; I think the key term here is "text", like text nodes in the DOM. So once a parent starts drawing stuff over text, the child elements can't make it stop. They can however add more decorations. Clearly this is not a thing I've done much.

See this MDN page

I see "Text decorations are drawn across descendant text elements. This means that if an element specifies a text decoration, then a child element can't remove the decoration."
So, can anyone explain the behavior of inline-block?

@qrsngky - Atomic inline boxes like inline-block (also inline-flex, inline-grid, etc) are just an exception. Text-decoration is just defined not to propagate into them.

I see that the inline-block problem has been asked before here. It referred to older specs, but I found  an explanation in a newer link

Copied exact wording from
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration for reference: Note that text decorations are not propagated to any out-of-flow descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Quote from MDN link:

Text decorations are drawn across descendant text elements. This means that if an element specifies a text decoration, then a child element can't remove the decoration.

So, even though your <td> element specifies text-decoration: none, the text inside the <td> is still affected by the text-decoration of the <tr> element.
However, according to this specification:

Note that text decorations are not propagated to any out-of-flow descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

So a workaround is to add an inline-block element. For example, we can use a span element and style it as inline-block. And since there is nothing special about the span, the sizes of the other elements are the same before.


const toDoArray = {
  test: true,
}

var toDoElements = "<table style=\"width: 100%;\">";

for (var k in toDoArray) { // Loop through the object
  var trS = "";
  if (toDoArray[k]) {
    trS = `class="taskChecked"`
  }
  toDoElements +=
    `<tr ${trS} id="${k}-tr">
      <td onclick="checkOffToDo('${k}')" id = "${k}-td" border=none > ${k}</td>
      <td onclick="removeToDo('${k}')" class="toDoDeleteButton"><span>&times;</span></td>     
    </tr>`
}

toDoElements += "</table>";

document.getElementById("toDoList").innerHTML = toDoElements;
#toDoList { width: 200px; font-size: 3rem; }

.taskChecked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: violet;
  color: purple;
  background: orange;
}

.toDoDeleteButton {
  border: none;
  width: 8%;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration-color: aqua;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: blue;
}

.toDoDeleteButton > span{
  display: inline-block;
}
<div id="toDoList"></div>



I found that you don't even need .toDoDeleteButton > span {text-decoration: none;}.The text-decoration doesn't propagate to the span, unless you specify text-decoration: inherit for both the td and the span.

Your "taskDef" class has text-decoration: line-through. That's the <tr>, the whole row of the table. That will apply to both <td> elements in the table, the word and the "X".
Now, why the cell style is not overriding the row style, I cannot say. It clearly has the style (well, no strike-through). I can't say anything definitive, but if I were doing this I would not make a <td> element a "button"; instead put a real <button> in the cell and style it separately. That'll probably require some other changes for the font size etc.
This is strange.
edit: commenters have explained that it's specifically about text-decoration rules and how they operate on descendant text nodes.

Another way to fix this problem is to add a secondary class.
To explain the priority list, qrsngky already said that "a child element can't remove the decoration of a parent".
I just want to add to his answer by giving a second solution which worked better for my case:


const toDoArray = {
  test: true,
}

var toDoElements = "<table style=\"width: 100%;\">";

for (var k in toDoArray) { // Loop through the object
  var trS = "";
  if (toDoArray[k]) {
    trS = `class="taskChecked"`
  }
  toDoElements +=
    `<tr ${trS} id="${k}-tr">
      <td class="task" onclick="checkOffToDo('${k}')" id = "${k}-td" border=none > ${k}</td>
      <td onclick="removeToDo('${k}')" class="toDoDeleteButton">&times;</td>     
    </tr>`
}

toDoElements += "</table>";

document.getElementById("toDoList").innerHTML = toDoElements;
#toDoList { width: 200px; font-size: 3rem; }

.taskChecked .task{
   text-decoration: line-through;
 }

.taskChecked {
  text-decoration-color: violet;
  color: purple;
  background: orange;
}

.toDoDeleteButton {
  border: none;
  width: 8%;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration-color: aqua;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div id="toDoList"></div>




The most important thing is that text-decoration cant be inherited ,there are two lines are independent of each other in the test demo below,and in your case the parent text-decoration just on top of the child.


<style>
  div {
    text-decoration: line-through
  }
  span {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <span>text-decoration</span>
</div>




"Can't be inherited" is not the right concept. For example in `

text-decoration
` the span gets a line through it even though without the `text-decoration: inherit;` it would not.
@Alohci,The line you looked does not got from  span but div even if the content is in span but not in  div.

If you try this <div style="text-decoration: line-through"><span style="margin:10px;display:block;text-decoration:none">abc</span><span>cde</span></div> you can see that it's not a single line from the parent, but rather two lines, one for each child. If you change the "block" to "inline-block", then only one child has a line.

@qrsngky,yes ,you are right, so do you mean the 'inline-block'  affect the 'text-decoration'?

Basically, the "inline-block" prevents the text-decoration from being propagated to the children. But if you use "text-decoration: inherit" as well then the text-decoration can affect the children.
