CSS Class Priority in Blazor Webapp
I'm having an issue where, no matter what I try, one particular class's background-color is always the one to be displayed on the screen.
Code:
<style>
.btnClass {
    border-radius:6px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:1em;
}
.gray {
    background-color: #494949;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}
</style>

<button class="btnClass @(ExampleBoolean ? "fill" : "fill gray")">Example Button</button>
<button class="btnClass" @onclick="ChangeBool">Change Boolean</button>


@code {
    private bool ExampleBoolean = false;
    
    private void ChangeBool()
    {
        ExampleBoolean = !ExampleBoolean;
    }
}

I first tried taking the fill class out in front of the entire comparison like so:
<button class="btnClass fill @(ExampleBoolean ? "" : "gray")">Example Button</button>

And moving fill to be after gray, both inside and outside the @ bit of code, but none of them have worked. Can anyone explain what is going on and why?

This doesn't seem to be a blazor issue, as it can be reproduced with vanilla HTML and CSS https://jsfiddle.net/sogzb29u/

What's the rendermode for the page?

This could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css

You could add !important to the relevant style.

I'm no CSS expert. I don't know why exactly CSS works like this.
You've got two CSS classes: fill and gray, with the same specificity. You can only apply background-color once to the element, so CSS chooses the rule that was written last. Note that means the last style defined in <style>, not which class name is used in the class attribute.
You could re-order the entries in your <style> so that .gray is last.


.btnClass {
    border-radius:6px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:1em;
}
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}
.gray {
    background-color: #494949;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
<button class="btnClass fill">button with fill</button>
<button class="btnClass fill gray">button with fill and grey</button>



The other option is to change the .gray selector to be more specific, such as .fill.gray. This means "the element is both fill and gray". CSS will see this new rule is more specific and correctly override the styles from .fill.


.btnClass {
    border-radius:6px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:1em;
}
.fill.gray {
    background-color: #494949;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}
<button class="btnClass fill">button with fill</button>
<button class="btnClass fill gray">button with fill and grey</button>



You may want to rename all your rules to follow this "hierarchy". If fill should only be used on elements that are also btnClass, and gray only exists to augment fill, you could end up with this:
.btnClass {
  /* ... */
}
.btnClass.fill {
  /* ... */
}
.btnClass.fill.gray {
  /* ... */
}

You could also not define a background color on fill, and require that another color class be applied to set the color.
You could also slap !important to the end of .gray's background-color, but I'd recommend against doing that.

Thank you! I did not know you could have classes inherit from other classes in CSS; that's very handy.

It's not "inheriting" like you're used to in C#, it just looks like it does.

Oh, ok. Does it enable duplicate names based on the pattern they're written in, at least?

What do you mean by "duplicate names"? Remember that the rule .btnClass.fill.gray just means an element that has all three classes. The order (both in the rule and in the class attribute) does not matter.

Ah, ok. I was wondering if you could make two css classes fill.gray and hollow.gray and use them without issue, but ig not.

The period is simply a separator between the css classes. .btnClass.fill.gray is "a selector for the btnClass class, fill class, and gray class, and the element must use all three in any order". You can't have a css class with a period in the name, so hollow.gray is hollow and gray. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp
